# Tsung Load test - Websocket + XMPP + SSL

Tags: websocket, erlang, ejabberd, openfire, tsung

Recently we have started investigating possibilities of creating load test script using Tsung tool to run against our **XMPP server(Openfire)**.

I am using load balancer address as server server configuration, which distributes the load between Openfire cluster nodes and websocket port number is 7443.ATM my goal is to log into server using credentials and get the room count from server in particular venture.

Some how my script is unable to make requests to load balancer, I have verified in XMPP server logs just to make sure. I am not sure what I am missing in the configuration to make a successful authentication request, can some one help me to fix this please.

Protocol: Websocket 
Port: 7743 (SSL)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM '/home/prasad/Documents/tsung-1.6.0/tsung-1.0.dtd'>
<tsung loglevel='info' dumptraffic='false' version='1.0'>
    <clients>
        <client host='localhost' use_controller_vm='false'/>
    </clients>
    <servers>
        <server host='chat.ppc1.pgt01.gamesysgames.com' port='7443' type='websocket'/>
    </servers>
    <load>
        <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="2" unit="minute">
            <users interarrival="2" unit="second"></users>
        </arrivalphase>
    </load>
    <options>
        <option type='ts_jabber' name='global_number' value='100000' />
        <option type='ts_jabber' name='userid_max' value='100000' />
        <option type='ts_jabber' name='domain' value='chat' />
        <option type='ts_jabber' name='muc_service' value='jackpotjoy.chat' />
        <option name="websocket_path" value='/ws' />
    </options>
    <sessions>
        <session probability="100" name="websocket-example" type="ts_jabber">
            <request>
                <jabber type="connect" ack='local'>
                    <xmpp_authenticate username='' passwd='&lt;VENTURE&gt;jackpotjoy&lt;/VENTURE&gt;&lt;TOKEN TYPE="1"&gt;&lt;PUBLIC&gt;&lt;MEMBER-ID&gt;18118300&lt;/MEMBER-ID&gt;&lt;NAME&gt;media1&lt;/NAME&gt;&lt;EXPIRY-DATE&gt;1467207433297&lt;/EXPIRY-DATE&gt;&lt;/PUBLIC&gt;&lt;CIPHER-TEXT&gt;&lt;![CDATA[O9jTn2YZzMFwcLPdLbwiQ/PlKG5X47w6JYlfWJ6Yh+50XMcpWEHuGs0Q1qI9IjjpU1/n7cUsEc0MPsxyUkXexgMdMZqdhMG5+Kczf2T8Ma2JvzCYMIjnkuuqwUMhigVF28nhrfFLSeSVbv2PhWJ7XUedarkkVibKrVnQkkvCqkGB5oXZixu/TTJzpqb/wjuTOqRa+vmwz8l2Ljp/0hb/e3MHyLNcd21S]]&gt;&lt;/CIPHER-TEXT&gt;&lt;/TOKEN&gt;'/>
                </jabber>
            </request>
            <transaction name='authenticate'>
                <request>
                    <jabber type='auth_sasl' ack='local' />
                </request>
                <request>
                    <jabber type='connect' ack='local' />
                </request>
                <request>
                    <jabber type='auth_sasl_bind' ack='local' />
                </request>
                <request>
                    <jabber type='auth_sasl_session' ack='local'/>
                </request>
            </transaction>
            <request>
                <jabber type='presence:initial' ack='local' />
            </request>
            <transaction name='roster'>
                <request>
                    <jabber type='iq:roster:get' ack='local'></jabber>
                </request>
            </transaction>
            <transaction name='get_roomcount'>
                <request>
                    <jabber type='raw' ack='local' data='&lt;iq to="jackpotjoy@chat" type="get"&gt;&lt;query
                        xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items" node="roomcount" /&gt;&lt;/iq&gt;'/>
                    </request>
                </transaction>
                <transaction name='close'>
                    <request>
                        <jabber type="close" ack='local' />
                    </request>
                </transaction>
            </session>
        </sessions>
    </tsung>
```

I don't see any error messages in logs, can someone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,I can only speak a little English.
You can try to modify dumptraffic = 'true' and set loglevel attribute.

Please look the Tsung User's manual:

- 6.1. File structure

  If you add the attribute dumptraffic=”true”, all the traffic will be logged to a file.

Comment: HI @Le Li, yes I've changed dumptraffic flag to true and ran the script again and I've noticed this info in log file.



=INFO REPORT==== 29-Jun-2016::16:17:49 ===
       ts_job_notify:(6:<0.81.0>) No listen port defined, can't open listening socket (don't worry: it's normal if you don't use job notifications)


=INFO REPORT==== 29-Jun-2016::16:17:52 ===
    ts_config_server:(5:<0.69.0>) Undefined ports_range config


=INFO REPORT==== 29-Jun-2016::16:17:52 ===
    ts_config_server:(5:<0.69.0>) New arrival phase 1 for client "localhost" (last ? true): will start 60


Any idea ?

Comment: sorry,I don't understand what you mean . Do you want to generate 60 users? You can also use arrivalrate instead of interarrival. For example, if you want 60 new users per second, use: <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="10" unit="second"> <users arrivalrate="60" unit="second"></users></arrivalphase>

Comment: HI @Le Li, actually if you see my comment log message it says

1) No listen port defined, can't open listening socket (don't worry: it's normal if you don't use job notifications)
2)  Undefined ports_range config 

Does it stopping to get the authentication do you think ? I don't see any error message in Tsung debug log file.

Comment: I see. If you see nothing wrong, you can compile Tsung with full debugging: recompile with make debug, and don’t forget to set the loglevel to debug in the XML file.